# ¿Como mato hilos en python que no uso?

Tags: python, socket

Tengo un problema con hilos de un socket, cuando se conecta el programa al socket este crea un hilo y luego crea otro haciendo muchas sesiones, y esto hace que el programa mande muchas solicitudes, entonces lo que hice fue:

```
def reconsocketloop():
    shandle = cliente.socket
    while (1):
        shandle.close()
        shandle.start()
        time.sleep(120)

  socketloop = threading.Thread(target = reconsocketloop, daemon = True)
  socketloop.start()
```

El problema de esto es que en heroku llego un punto de que se sobre paso el uso de muchos hilos dandome este error:

```
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Como puedo matar los anteriores hilos que no se estan usando? Al principio funciono lo que hice, pero luego de unos días llego a ese punto

Comment: No puedes matar un hilo. El hilo debe morir por sí solo (basta que la función que está siendo ejecutada por el hilo retorne). Lo que puedes evitar es crear hilos sin control. Puedes en cambio tener un pool de hilos (creados de antemano) y asignarles trabajos según lleguen. Mirate la librería futures y en concreto el [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor). Por otro lado no se entiende bien en tu pregunta qué es `shandle` ¿es un socket o un hilo? ¿qué hace `shandle.start()`?)

Comment: Shandle es como el cliente de la app, se conecta y desconecta, aunque este error no es de mi codigo si no de la api en sí de la que uso, mirare lo de ThreadPoolExecutor, graciaas

Comment: Puedes detener un *hilo* ejecutando `sys.exit()` en dicho hilo. El resto de *threads* seguirán funcionando.